# Opening specific ViewController when selecting item from side menu?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have `CenterTableViewController`, Left, and Right
Center is the main view when app starts, and Left and Right are side menu's, that are opened when swiped or clicked on navigation controller .`Buttons`
Both Left and Right `TableViewControllers` have their number of items, right one has around 10. When one of those 10 items is clicked, it needs to pop up a specific `ExampleViewController`.That `ViewController` appears without navigation controller (and I need it with it), and in that navigation controller I need a back button, that will send me back to `CenterTableViewController`.

Up until now, I reached to `RightTableViewController`, in its class witch is named the same, i have this method

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        switch (indexPath.row){

    case 0:

        break;
    case 1:

        break;
    case 2:

        break;
    case 3:

        break;
    case 4:

        break;
    case 5:

        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Kurs_Evra") as! KursEvraViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)


        break;
    case 6:

        break;
    case 7:

        break;
    case 8:

        break;
    case 9:

        break;

    default:
        println("JBG")
    }
}
```

In case 5, it opens `ViewController` that I need, but it opens in `RightTableViewController` instead of Center (because of that "self" part).

Also, when that is opened, how to create navigation controller and a back button on that `ViewController` that just opened?

Answer (score 0):

If your centre view controller has a navigation controller, then use that for the navigation. For instance in your right navigation controller, instead of pushing the view controller, fire a notification to navigate to that page.
Then in your centre controller listen for the notification and do the navigation from there.

This is what you should do:

In your switch statement for case 5, change the code to this: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MenuItemNotification", object: "Kurs_Evra”)

In your CenterViewController in the viewDidLoad method, add this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("MenuItemNotification", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { [weak self] notif in

        if let strongSelf = self {

            if let segueIdentifier = notif.object as? String {

                strongSelf.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier, sender: nil)

            }

        }

    }
```

In the above code I assume you have a segue setup called Kurs_Evra and not just a storyboard Id. If you do not want to use a segue, then use the code you had for case 5

Comment: Yes, Center VC has a navigation controller.
But can you give example code for that notification fire, both for right and center VC.

Answer (score 0):

this was not so hard.

Go to your Right or Left side menu, in class create method didSelectRowAtIndex path, and use switch statement like above.

Then, in case post what code you need, and this is how you post a new storyboard ABOVE your navigation stack and your main ViewController

let Example = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExampleViewController") as! ExampleViewController

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: Example)

and finally...

self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

using "present" will open a new controller you created, in this case ExampleViewController, and it will be first in new navigation stack.If you wish to close, or simulate back button, simply connect action to a button and call:

self.dismissViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)